# How to make VSTS detect an error & set the task as failed? Angular CLI

Tags: angular, npm, sass, azure-devops, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI to build the project on VSTS and I have a npm task to build the project. I want that task to throw an error if something went wrong, but it doesn't.

So, the task I ran is "ng build" from Angular CLI and I typed an error on the scss file. It detects the error and print it on the console, but It goes to the next task and understand that one as a good one (it shouldn't be like that, it should stop and throw the error)

For a clearer output, see attached image:

[image]

Here the task:

[image]

**Noticed that the task "build" is declared on package.json as a Angular CLI task, see next pic**

[image]

Any ideas? I think it's related to the Angular CLI because with Gulp, If I do the compile scss task, it works as expected.

Thanks :)

***EDIT 1:*** I have "run-script" for the npm command which is the same than normal "run", I tried both, see more info here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

***EDIT 2:*** Added screenshot of the error which should be detected and throw an error and it's detected but the build proceed successfully and it shouldn't

[image]

Comment: Which build step you used to run npm run-script? Is it Command line step? In addition, could you share a simple project that we can make the test directly?

Comment: It's a npm task, defined in the package.json as attached, which run "ng build" which is a Angular CLI command. Added an Edit. Reply that to your question? thanks @starain

Comment: Yes, I know, could you share a simple project (Angular) that we can make a test directly?

Comment: Hi @starain thanks for the support, the problem is the sass error is not detected, and sorry, I can't disengage that part from the project, any another solution? Added screenshot :)

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: hi @user911 running AOT on VSTS throws an error when there is an error, tried that and it worked. can you try and let me know if that solves your problem too?